# JAVA prevent SQL injection reading JSON from file

Tags: java, json, sql-injection

I would like to prevent possible SQL injections when retrieving values from a JSON string stored in a text file. The JSON string is converted into a JAVA POJO and the values are used in a query generated dynamically inside the code. The solutions I have found uses a connection to the database which I don't have because my SQL query is being sent as string to an external client; I don't have direct access to the database. I know that sending the a SQL query as string might not be the best design but the client I am using only has that option.

Comment: This is an insane way to design an interface, not only for sql injection potential but because the server has no control of what queries are run. It seems like your only option is to use white-lists of allowed characters to rule out escaping.

Comment: I agree the interface I am using is badly designed, but that is what I have. I thought about a regex to control the input but that may cause issue with valid input in the future; although it still an option. Thanks